# Center a menu in a header with custom theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm doing some work for a client and he has a custom theme and I can't for the life of me center the menu options in his header. He doesn't have the option to change the alignment in the theme editor so I'm stuck trying to edit the code. I can post the entire header code here:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div class='container'>
<div class='header_wrap'>
<div class='header'>
  <h1>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
      <span><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></span>
    </a>
  </h1>
  <div class='clock_wrap'>
    <div class='title'>
       Income Tax Deadline
    </div>
    <div class='clock'></div>
  </div>
<div class='clear'></div>
  <?php
  $description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
  if ( $description || is_customize_preview() ) : ?>
  <p class="desc"><?php echo $description; ?></p>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <div class='nav'>
    <a href='/'>Home</a>
<?php wp_nav_menu( array(
  'menu'            => 'main',
  'container_class' => false,
  'container'       => ''
));
?>
    </div><!-- nav -->
  </div><!-- header -->
 </div><!-- header_wrap -->
<div class="content">
```

Sorry for the formatting, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you shear a live link so we can check and try to find out what is the issue ?

Comment: http://elitetax.ca/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your theme main CSS file find out this class  .header_wrap .header .nav and add text-align: center just like below

```
.header_wrap .header .nav {
   text-align: center;
}
```

See this image below I mark this. It is now without changing your .header_wrap .header .nav class now your nav bar in the left side

http://prnt.sc/cn1kq4

Now again see this image below I mark it after adding text-align: center; .header_wrap .header .nav class now your nav bar showing in the center.

http://prntscr.com/cn1mpq

I hope this time you will fix it.

Comment: Where would I put that in here?

`.header_wrap .header .nav {
      border-bottom: solid 1px #efd6b1;
      border-top: solid 3px #efd6b1;
      margin-top: 16px;
      padding: 16px 24px; }
      .header_wrap .header .nav a {
        color: black;
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-right: 16px;
        text-transform: uppercase; }
        .header_wrap .header .nav a:hover {
          text-decoration: none;
          color: #efd6b1; }`

Comment: In this code .header_wrap .header .nav { border-bottom: solid 1px #efd6b1; border-top: solid 3px #efd6b1; margin-top: 16px; padding: 16px 24px; text-align: center; } see this just last line text-align: center I added

Comment: If you have facing trouble to put this code in a right place just past this code bottom of your theme main CSS file.

Comment: All of these did not work. Is it possible that he has text-align: absolute in his code that is making this not work? I am checking his entire code now

Comment: Hey, check my answer I just edited it. I hope this time you will understand and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

When examining your page in the browser tools, I only added this to the CSS and the menu was centered:

```
.nav {
  text-align: center;
}
```

addition: If it still doesn't work, try adding `!important`, like

```
.nav {
  text-align: center !important;
}
```

Comment: I tried including this code in many different places in the CSS, it did not work. Should I make another topic and include the entire CSS code for the theme? Or here is a link to the website so you can view the source code: http://elitetax.ca/

Comment: please note my edited answer - it's really a very simple solution

Answer (score 0):

As others users said, it is pretty hard without looking at any CSS, but my favorite form of centering objects in containers in CSS is the next.

```
.Object-to-center {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```